# Problem of understanding a vector calculus formula

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I have encountered the following formula during my course in electromagnetic field theory:
$$ {\displaystyle {\vec {\nabla }}\times \varphi {\vec {A}}=\varphi {\vec {\nabla }}\times {\vec {A}}-{\vec {A}}\times {\vec {\nabla }}\varphi .} $$
I just do not understand the menaing of the first part in front of the minus sign. I have also seen a similar situation in the following formula:
$$ {\displaystyle {\vec {\nabla }}\times ({\vec {A}}\times {\vec {B}})=({\vec {B}}\cdot {\vec {\nabla }}){\vec {A}}-{\vec {B}}({\vec {\nabla }}\cdot {\vec {A}})+{\vec {A}}({\vec {\nabla }}\cdot {\vec {B}})-({\vec {A}}\cdot {\vec {\nabla }}){\vec {B}}.} $$ But now with a Vectorfield and not with a scalar function. Can somebody please help me with this lack of understanding?

Comment: Do you know the name of the formula? If so, please share.

Comment: Do you understand it now ? ${\vec {\nabla }}\times (\varphi {\vec {A}})=\varphi ({\vec {\nabla }}\times {\vec {A}})-{\vec {A}}\times ({\vec {\nabla }}\varphi)$ ? If not what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It is the order of the scalar function an the nabla operator. If the order is the other way around i know that it is the gradient of the field. But what exactly is the geometric interpretation of a scalar function times the nabla operator?

Comment: Using parentheses I wrote in the comment that the expression in question is the curl of $\vec{A}$ (which is a vector) *times* the scalar function $\varphi\,.$

Comment: The second formula is a little trickier. $\vec B(\vec\nabla\cdot \vec A)$ is just the vector field $\vec B$ times the scalar field $\vec\nabla\cdot \vec A$. However, if $\vec A = (A_x, A_y, A_z)$ and $\vec B = (B_x, B_y, B_z)$, then $$\vec B\cdot \vec\nabla = B_x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + B_y\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} + B_z\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$$ is a scalar differential operator. By applying to the vector field $\vec A$, they mean $$(\vec B\cdot \vec\nabla)\vec A = (\vec B\cdot \vec\nabla A_x, \vec B\cdot \vec\nabla A_y, \vec B\cdot \vec\nabla A_z)$$